# Returning a string to JS function from Android Activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am passing a value to a JS function from native android activity, but the function is not being called

**java method**

```
public void Jmethod()
{
//index is the WebView
index.loadUrl("javascript:  window.SetImage("+selectedImagePath+");");
}
```

**JS function**

```
 function SetImage(ImgPath)
    {
     alert('this function called');

    }
```

and here is what the LogCat says

```
03-31 12:27:23.668: D/webview(30574): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
03-31 12:27:24.483: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30574): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-31 12:27:24.493: D/chromium(30574): Unknown chromium error: -6
03-31 12:27:27.438: D/WebView(30574): loadUrlImpl: called
03-31 12:27:27.438: D/webcore(30574):  CORE loadUrl: called
03-31 12:27:27.438: D/webkit(30574): Firewall not null
03-31 12:27:27.438: D/webkit(30574): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
```

i am successfully calling java functions from webview, but this thing is not working, kindly tell me where i am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabledJavascript??

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

You might also want to remove space between javascript and window.SetImage as well.

Comment: Please check space between javascript and window.SetImage as well.

Comment: Ah it seems you need to register Javascript Interface as well. So you do it something like this... `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "MyAndroid");` You can have a look at this [link] http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.fi/2011/10/calling-javascript-function-from.html[/link]

Comment: its already added... all the problem was these '' little devils

Comment: hmm, I noticed you are now having too many ", it would be easy to use  ' <string> ', than '"<string>"'

Answer (score 0):

When you say the javascript function isn't called, do you mean that, or do you mean that the alert dialog is not shown?

If the latter, you need to set a default WebChromeClient on your WebView to get the UI to display.

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: well alert is not shown , i am checking it in this way . . .

Answer (score 0):

I have tested locally , it work for me. I hope you will get some idea from that :)

//Java

```
final String image = "image url";

index.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

index.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//make sure to put the single quote inside argument.
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.SetImage('" + image + "')"); 
}

});
index.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
index.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

//This function will be inside index.html

```
function SetImage(imageUrl)
{
alert(imageUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was only these '' ... 
it worked fine by adding

> index.loadUrl("javascript:SetImage('"+selectedImagePath+"')");